# C# running WPF generating csproj file and causing a fail build

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So, the short of it is, I have a program in building to just help with a thing me and some friends do, I checked the program over a couple times but nothing I can see makes since.

```
C:\Users\Drpep\OneDrive\Documents\CPP\PokeDraft\Pokedraft\MainWindow.xaml(230,47): error CS0102: The type 'MainWindow' already contains a definition for 'mainGrid' [{}\PokeDraft\Pokedr
aft\Pokedraft_py5f5vc4_wpftmp.csproj]

The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.
```

I get this error

I'm using Visual Studio 22 and can see the file pop into existance for like 1 second and is gone after and the py5... part changes every time i try to build and run the code. not sure what to do. because I need to define the mainGrid in the Cs file of the window to access it. but when i do, it tells me i already did, but when i dont it doesnt exist.

```xaml
<Window x:Class="Pokedraft.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Pokedraft"
    xmlns:linq="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    Background="#333333">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" /> <!-- Options Menu -->
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" /> <!-- Main Content -->
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- Options Menu -->
        <Border Grid.Column="0" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
            <StackPanel Margin="10">
                <!-- Name of the Draft -->
                <TextBlock Text="Name of the Draft:" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBox FontSize="20" />

                <!-- Dropdown for Draft Selection -->
                <TextBlock Text="Select Draft:" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <ComboBox FontSize="20" />

                <TextBlock Text="# of Spins:" FontSize="24" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <ComboBox FontSize="20" ItemsSource="{Binding SpinValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSpinValue, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedIndex="0">
                    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Style>
                    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ComboBox>

                <!-- Exclude section -->
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="Exclude:" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="Legendaries" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                Margin="10,0">
                                <TextBlock Text="UBs" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                                <TextBlock Text="Mythicals" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <!-- Gens section -->
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel Margin="10">
                        <TextBlock Text="Gens:" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <UniformGrid Rows="3" Columns="3" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="3" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="4" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="5" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="6" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="7" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="8" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                            <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                IsChecked="True">
                                <TextBlock Text="9" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </CheckBox>
                        </UniformGrid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <!--Monotype
                Section-->
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="DisableMonotypeCheckBox" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                            Checked="DisableMonotypeCheckBox_Checked"
                            Unchecked="DisableMonotypeCheckBox_Unchecked">
                            <TextBlock Text="Enable" FontSize="20" Foreground="White"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </CheckBox>

                        <TextBlock Text="Monotype:" FontSize="24" Foreground="White"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MonotypeOptions}" Background="Transparent"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=DisableMonotypeCheckBox, Path=IsChecked}">
                            <ListBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="ListBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </ListBox.Style>
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <UniformGrid Rows="6" Columns="3" Margin="5" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <RadioButton GroupName="MonotypeGroup">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20"
                                            Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </RadioButton>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <!-- Spin Button -->
                <Button x:Name="SpinButton" Content="SPIN" FontSize="36" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White"
                    Padding="20" Width="300" Margin="0 0 20 20"
                    Click="SpinButton_Click">
                    <Button.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder" Background="#333333" BorderBrush="#555555"
                                BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="Background"
                                        Value="#555555" />
                                    <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush"
                                        Value="#888888" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Button.Template>
                </Button>                          

                <!-- Save and Load Buttons -->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Button Content="Save" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Padding="10" Width="100"
                        Margin="0 0 20 0">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="border" Background="#333333" BorderBrush="#555555"
                                    BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background"
                                            Value="#555555" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Content="Load" FontSize="20" Foreground="White" Padding="10" Width="100"
                        Margin="0 0 20 0">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="border" Background="#333333" BorderBrush="#555555"
                                    BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background"
                                            Value="#555555" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>

            </StackPanel>
        </Border>

        <!-- Main Content -->
        <Border Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Margin="10">
            <Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
                <!-- Add your other UI elements here -->
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I havent tried much of anything as of yet, I tired making a new name for the mainGrid, but it always errors saying the new name is duplicated.

Comment: "*I need to define the mainGrid in the Cs file*" - no, you don't. That field is automatically generated by the build process.

Comment: @Clemens Maybe VSCode was causing an error because I just found out VSCode has some issues with this type of coding.